# Find total amount as per selected plan

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have a 7 days product plan with different product price ,

If user has selected plan for mon,tue,wed its respective price is 100,200,300
now I has to provide this product to user for 7 times.means ,

user will get product on mon , tue, wed then next week again mon, tue ,wed and after that week only on mon

so i need to calculate its total price likewise

```
var total = 100 * 3 , 200 * 2 , 300 * 2 ;
```

How to achieve this ?
I have tried so far ,

```
var mon=document.getElementById("mon").value;
var tue=document.getElementById("tue").value;
var wed=document.getElementById("wed").value;
var thu=document.getElementById("thu").value;
var fri=document.getElementById("fri").value;
var sat=document.getElementById("sat").value;
var sun=document.getElementById("sun").value;
var total=0;
for(i=1;i<=7;i++){

if(mon != ''){ 
total=total+ +mon;
}
if(tue != ''){
total=total+ +tue;
}
if(wed != ''){
total=total+ +wed;
}
if(thu != ''){
total=total+ +thu;
}
if(fri != ''){
total=total+ +fri;
}
if(sat != ''){
total=total+ +sat;
}
if(sun != ''){
total=total+ +sun;
}
alert(total );
}
```

but it is not correct .It counts monday 7 times

Comment: Nirali , why two `+` in `total=total+ +mon;`

Comment: *var total = 100 * 3 , 200 * 2...*  how you get 3 and 2 ?

Comment: @epodax removed php tag

Comment: @splash58 that is the logic i want , say user has selected plan for 3 days , then I must provide that product to user for 7 days , so mon , tue, wed then again mon, tue, wed then only on monday .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Put  values into array
a = [];
var a[0]=document.getElementById("mon").value;
var a[1]=document.getElementById("tue").value;
var a[3]=document.getElementById("wed").value;
...
// Dont forget to test that sum(a) != 0 to avoid endless loop 

var total=0;
i = 7;
p = 0;
// Loop while all 7 days will be found
while(i>0) {
  // Find next not empty
  while(a[p] == '') p = ++p % 7;
  total += parseInt(a[p]);
  i--;
  p = ++p % 7
}
console.log(total );
```

[demo](https://eval.in/579333)

Comment: if i want same function for 30 days then what should i change ?

Comment: You want to count 30 days or change days of week to days of month ?

Comment: change days to days of month , means if selected days are mon,tue,wed then it should count till 30 days

Comment: Change i=7 to i=30